# How to check wether script is running on workstation or on server

Tags: linux, shell

What is reliable way to know if <s>user session from which the shell scipt is run is graphic session?</s>
Script is started on worstation machine with graphics?

I can think of some options but all of them is distro specific, I'm looking for as distro agnostic solution as possible.

UPD:
Sorry, I've understood that I had incorrect wording.

I need to determine if machine has graphics and act accordingly, script could be started from non-graphical session, e.g.  ssh, but on workstation, I need to process this case as workstation.

UPD2:

I'm writing script to seal vm template. I don't know in advance on which distro (mostly Ubuntu, Centos and Manjaro but who knows) or on which type of vm (workstation or server) it will be run.
I have several distro specific steps, I wanted to separate ws/server case selection and processing from distro specific processing because most likely it will lead to code duplication sooner or later.

E.g.

```
systemctl enable initial-setup.service
touch /.unconfigured
```

should be ran in case of centos/fedora/rhel workstation and not on server.

Comment: I had a similar problem once, I think I ended up looking at  `$DISPLAY`. I'm way super not confident enough to make this an answer, though...

Comment: I'm not confident in my solution that much that it didn't even made it to question)

Comment: Why do you think a GUI session is a reliable indicator of the machine type? Many servers run X11, too.

Comment: One could [check from terminal if any GUI is installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237598/266568).

Answer (score 2):

Check if `DISPLAY` is set and begins with `localhost` or a colon. This obviously doesn't reveal the type of hardware, but this heuristic should do what you *actually* seem to be asking.

```sh
case $DISPLAY in
    localhost:* | :*) xeyes;; # we are graphical
    *) shutdown -h now;;
esac
```

I put in the `*)` case just to show how to run something when you are *not* graphical; probably take it out completely if you don't need that.

Comment: Thank you for responce, I need to achieve a bit different thing, I've had confusing question details(but title is correct) sorry.

Comment: It's even less clear now. Really, can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? In the question itself.